# cannot connect to HTTPS and for HTTP say cannot install applications because the certificate when I want to use .plist for download App

Tags: ios, swift, ipa

I want to download `.ipa` from url ,i create`.plist` and upload on `dropbox`,and create `.index`file with this cod :

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.dropbox.com/s/.../testInits.plist">Install App</a>
```

but when open the `.index` and click on `Install App`  the  [show this Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrEzy.jpg) and don't open .plist until show message for installation app

I try this `.index` on the other with HTTP server,but show this
[show this Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBfKP.jpg) saying:`cannot install applications because the certificate for p..ti.ir not valid`

this code for `.index`

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://p..ti.ir/.../testInit.plist" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

I don't know about certificate

may have my code `.index` problem?!

What should i do ?

Comment: Dropbox stop offering public downloads unless you have a premium account. Might this be an issue?

Comment: No,i try the other server but ,showing this error

Comment: The other server was it HTTPS? Because it needs to be and have a valid TLS certificate.

Comment: yes,the other  server HTTPS too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have to use this :

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/.....
```

for download from dropBox
so the .plist is :

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/.../testInits.plist">Install App</a>
```

and should use HTTPS from download